# Grammar error in Documentation vote up privilege page

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, help-center

[This doesn't make sense:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/docs-voting)

> #### When should I vote up?
>
> Whenever you encounter an examples especially useful, or a topic request you want to see responded to.

Presumably, one of the following was intended:

> #### When should I vote up?
>
> Whenever you encounter an example which is especially useful, or a topic request you want to see responded to.

or perhaps

> #### When should I vote up?
>
> Whenever you find an example especially useful, or encounter a topic request you want to see responded to.

or, imitating the language of [the main SO Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up):

> #### When should I vote up?
>
> Whenever you encounter an example that you feel is especially useful, or a topic request you want to see responded to.

Comment: The [main SO help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) says "Whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment **that you feel is** especially useful, vote it up!"

Comment: @Josh good find, have edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.